# Как загрузить несколько файлов

Tags: php, html

Помогите, не могу сделать загрузку нескольких файлов. Ошибок не выдает, но файлы не загружает. 
Код:

```
    <form name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="action">
   <input type="file" name="images[]" id="img" class="nameForm" multiple="true">
    </form>
    === 
    $imagespost = $_POST['images'];
    $images = array();
    for($x=0; $x<count($imagespost); $x++) {

    $img = $_FILES['images']['type'][$x];

    if($img > 1024*1024)
    {
        $size = false;
    }
    if($img == 'image/gif') {
        $end = ".gif";
    }
    elseif($img == 'image/png') {
        $end = ".png";
    }
    elseif($img == 'image/jpeg') {
        $end = ".jpeg";
    }

    if ($img != 'image/gif' && $img != 'image/png' && $img != 'image/jpeg') {
        $type = false;
    }

    $arr=array('a','b','c','q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','z','x','v','n','m','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0',);
    $nameimg = $arr[rand(0,count($arr))].$arr[rand(0,count($arr))].$arr[rand(0,count($arr))].$arr[rand(0,count($arr))].$arr[rand(0,count($arr))].$arr[rand(0,count($arr))].$arr[rand(0,count($arr))].$arr[rand(0,count($arr))];

        if($size!=false & $type!=false) {
            if(move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$x], '/img/'.$nameimg.$end)) {
            array_push ($images, $nameimg.$end);
            }
        }

    }
```

UPD: переработал под цикл foreach, но результат прежний.

```
    foreach($_FILES['images']['name'] as $k=>$file) {

    $img = $_FILES['images']['type'][$k];

    if($img > 1024*1024)
    {
        $size = false;
    }
    if($img == 'image/gif') {
        $end = ".gif";
    }
    elseif($img == 'image/png') {
        $end = ".png";
    }
    elseif($img == 'image/jpeg') {
        $end = ".jpeg";
    }

    if ($img != 'image/gif' && $img != 'image/png' && $img != 'image/jpeg') {
        $type = false;
    }

    $arr=array('a','b','c','q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','z','x','v','n','m','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0',);
    $nameimg = $arr[rand(0,count($arr))].$arr[rand(0,count($arr))].$arr[rand(0,count($arr))].$arr[rand(0,count($arr))].$arr[rand(0,count($arr))].$arr[rand(0,count($arr))].$arr[rand(0,count($arr))].$arr[rand(0,count($arr))];

        if($size!=false & $type!=false) {
            if(move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$k], '../files/images/'.$nameimg.$end)) {
            array_push ($images, $nameimg.$end);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Вопрос все еще остается открытым :) Неужели никто не знает?

Comment: Скажите, а вы права для записи выдали?

Comment: Права выданы 777

Comment: Хм... заслешил if($size!=false & $type!=false) - загрузка идет нормально. Но почему так? Вроде проверка задана верно

Comment: Может if($size!=false && $type!=false) поэтому ?

Comment: Да, из-за него. А что там неверно?

Answer (score 2):

1) при использовании оператор **&&**, если первая операция будет **false**, то проверка второй операции **не** выполняется

Например:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$a = 1; 
$b = 2;

if($a > 1 && $b/0 > 2 ) {

    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'no true';
}

?>
```

Результат: no true (т.е первое условие false и дальше он не проверяет и ошибки деления на ноль $b/0 тоже не дает)

2) при использовании оператора **&**, если первая операция будет **false**, то вторая операция **тоже** выполняется

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $a = 1; 
    $b = 2;

    if($a > 1 & $b/0 > 2 ) {

        echo 'true';
    } else {
        echo 'no true';
    }

    ?>
```

Результат: Warning: Division by zero in C:\web\www\area\test.php on line 8 (т.е он проверил оба условия и т.к деление на 0 является ошибкой, то соответствующая ошибка и вывалилась)